# How to deploy to github with file pattern on travis?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have created a simple travis configuration which packages an app and tries to deploy the archive file to github.
The problem is, I would like to have the version number part of the file name, so i require to use a pattern for the filename. I simply can't get it to work.

Configuration is currently:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  file: "build/distributions/worktrail-app-hub-sync*.zip"
  on:
    repo: worktrail/worktrail-app-hub-sync
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

But it fails with: "/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/octokit-3.3.1/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb:86:in `initialize': No such file or directory - build/distributions/worktrail-app-hub-sync*.zip (Errno::ENOENT)" - but the file is certainly there: build/distributions/worktrail-app-hub-sync-0.0.1.zip

Example run: https://travis-ci.org/worktrail/worktrail-app-hub-sync/builds/35704111
travis.yml: https://github.com/worktrail/worktrail-app-hub-sync/blob/0.0.1/.travis.yml

Is this supported by travis deployment, or is there any workaround for this use case?

Comment: could they make doc about it things would be a bit easier..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wildcards are supported by now if you enable the `file_glob` option. This is how I deploy a build `.deb` file to GitHub releases:

```
before_deploy:
  - export RELEASE_PKG_FILE=$(ls *.deb)
  - echo "deploying $RELEASE_PKG_FILE to GitHub releases"
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: YOUR_ENCRYPTED_API_KEY
  file_glob: true
  file: "${RELEASE_PKG_FILE}"
  on:
    tags: true
```

Setting up is easy by executing `travis setup releases` with a dummy filename and modifying `.travis.yml` afterwards.

Comment: even "file_glob: true" is no longer needed nowadays

Comment: The "file_glob: true" is a must for me, so @hennr information seems incorrect.

Comment: @cburgmer works for me without it: https://github.com/hennr/marabou/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: And clearly the shell is resolving the glob pattern for your setup?

Answer (score 12):

```
deploy:
  file_glob: true
  file: "build/distributions/worktrail-app-hub-sync*.zip"
```

[example](https://github.com/eHanlin/hLog2Client-Java/blob/master/.travis.yml#L10)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, wildcard patterns don't work at the moment, but we'll have a look into making that possible on Travis CI.