# Use Travis CI releases to upload unknown file

Tags: java, github, jar, travis-ci

I would like to use the Travis deploy releases feature to upload compiled jar files to Github, per the instructions here http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/. However, as far as i can tell it is absolutely necessary to know the exact file names beforehand. However, the file i want to upload will have a different name when there is a version change.

I could add a script to discover the file and rename it, but then it would be uploaded with the wrong name.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use wildcards or to have Travis upload an entire folder?

Many thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929225/how-to-deploy-to-github-with-file-pattern-on-travis?rq=1