# Deploy jar File using Travis CI and Gradle automatic build count

Tags: java, github, gradle, build.gradle, travis-ci

So I figured out how gradle etc works.
I heard about travis CI and got it working.
Now the last thing I want to achieve, is to make gradle create jar files of the source folder and to give the file names according to their build number, so that none of the previous files get overwritten.
I heard about the GitHub deployment possibillity, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure that's possible.

According to [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases), you need a section in your `.travis.yml` for
`deploy`. Specifically, you need to switch it on for when you create a Tag in your repository, and you will need to tell Travis to throw nothing away
prematurely.  Quoting the docs for the **deploy world** snippet:

```
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key: "GITHUB OAUTH TOKEN"
  file: "FILE TO UPLOAD"
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    tags: true
```

Then your **second question** of how to put version numbers in the binary name: You will want to include `file_glob: true` to `.travis.yml` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929225/how-to-deploy-to-github-with-file-pattern-on-travis) for details).

I am not really familiar with the capablities of Grunt to copy or rename files, but you can always use a shell script containing something along the following lines:

```
orig=origfile.jar
tag=$(git tag --points-at=$(git rev-parse HEAD))
cp "$orig" "${orig%.jar}_${tag}.jar"
```